# Load resource DLL with ResolveEventHandler

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, assembly-loading, resource-dll

I have a handler to help resolve DLLs via `ResolveEventHandler`. But when I have this handler I get an error about resources DLL. Which I even don't see on my PC (though I have instances of this DLL for other cultures like es-ES, de-De, ...):

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.resources, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=**en-US**, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

When I run w/o the handler I see the following assembly loaded:

> Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a

What should I do in the handler or in somewhere else to resolve this resources DLL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ups, have just found an answer. I added the following check inside the handler:

```
if (File.Exists(dllPath))
{
     return Assembly.LoadFrom(dllPath);
}
else
{
    return null;
}
```